# Find when the population doubles?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

For a given rate of population increse *g* (that is, *g*% increase), in order to find out the time *t* that the population doubles, I have worked out that I need to find *t* in terms of *g* in the following equation:

$$2 = \sum_{n=0}^t \binom{t}{n} . {(\frac{g}{100})}^{n}$$

but I am stuck here. Could you give me some insights?

Comment: RHS is $(1 + g/100)^t$. So...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binomial theorem states that:

$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n}\choose{k}}x^ky^{n-k}$$

Using this, with $y=1$, we see that the RHS is equal to: $$\left(1+\frac{g}{100}\right)^t$$

This is perfectly logical. Each year the population is multiplied by $1+g\%$. So after $t$ years it's multiplied by $(1+g\%)^t$.

Now to find $t$ you just solve $2=(1+g/100)^t$, which gives
$$t=\frac{\log(2)}{\log(1+g/100)}$$

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain how we get to that?

Comment: Oh I get it now. But still, further visitors may benefit from an explanation.

Comment: Yes, I have edited.